# What does "stereo" mean in "ıf you ever see your 'stereo' again"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> After all you don not really want to hear that you will be lucky ıf you ever see your 'stereo' again.

"Stereo" was not clear when I checked it out by dictionary what it meant, the explanation was not suitable for the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean **stereo**. It is an item of electrical equipment that you can use to play CDs and records.

> [image: stereo]

The sentence:

> After all, you do not really want to hear that you will be lucky ıf you ever see your **stereo** again.

This is most likely a parent or carer talking to a child.

The child won't be happy to hear:

> After all, **you do not really want to hear**

He will be fortunate/lucky if he gets his  stereo back:

> you will be lucky ıf you ever see your **stereo** again.

By using the phrase **if you ever see** the person is implying that his stereo might be taken away forever as a punishment.

Comment: It could have been stolen.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey true; that is just the most common example

Comment: thank you for explanation but still somethings are not clear for me.the stereo means,like voice that his or her words are about somethng

Comment: @Ferhat, a stereo is the thing shown in the image. An electronic system for playing music or other recorded or broadcast sounds.